# Merge multiple csv files that share only two variables

Tags: python, loops, csv, merge, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read in multiple csv files (20) that only share two columns how do i read in this data ?

example

csv1,csv2

csv1 varaibles [a,b,c]
csv2 variables  [d,e,a,c]

jointed_csv = [a,b,c,d,e]

looping all csv files ?

Comment: Do they have the same number of rows, or do you have to match up the columns to find a match?  Do all 20 files have to combine into one?

Comment: Please provide sample input (modify the sample if it contains anything sensitive). A minimal example would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.